# Cannot select a cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It is probably a very stupid thing but I am really going mad about this.
Let's say that I have the following dataframe (the table is actually much bigger but this is not important):

```
Index   Call Rate   Array Info.X    Array Info.Y
    0   "0.993922"  20202821    R01C01
    1   "0.723922"  20217347    R01C01
    2   "0.493922"  20257906    R01C01
    3   "0.723922"  20355030    R01C01
```

I am trying to use the following code to extract the value "Call Rate" for the combination "20257906" (folder) & R01C01 (current_section).

```
call_rate = samples_table.loc[((samples_table['Array Info.Y'] == current_section))]# & (samples_table['Array Info.X'] == (f"{folder}")),'Call Rate']
call_rate = float(numpy.round(call_rate, decimals=4))
```

However, the variable call_rate appears to be empty so there's nothing to round.
The information is decently in the dataframe so I assume that this is caused by something wrong in the first line of my code.

I am using Spyder and the variable explorer describes the variable "call_rate" as:

```
Series; (0,); Series of pandas.core.series module
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it! The following should give you what you desire:

```
current_section = 'R01C01'
folder = 20257906

call_rate = samples_table[(samples_table['Array Info.X'] == folder) & (df['Array Info.Y'] == current_section)]['Call Rate']

call_rate = np.round(float(call_rate.iloc[0]), decimals=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can do in this way:

```
current_section = 'R01C01'
folder = 20257906
call_rate = samples_table.loc[(samples_table['Array Info.Y'] == current_section) & (samples_table['Array Info.X'] == folder),'Call Rate']
call_rate = numpy.round(float(call_rate.iloc[0][1:-1]), decimals=4)
print (call_rate)
```

Output:

```
0.4939
```